# NOT the most important const.. but what is this?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, object-lifetime

This outputs `F~` but I was expecting `~F`

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int _x;
    operator const int & () const {return _x;}
    ~ Foo () {std :: cout << "~";}
};

void foo (const int &)
{
    std :: cout << "F";
}

int main ()
{
    foo (Foo ());
}
```

I constructed this as a counterexample to show that the most-important-const is an exception rather than a rule. It is normally written as

> when a const reference binds to a temporary, then the lifetime of that temporary is extended to the lifetime of the reference

I was trying to illustrate that, although `Foo()` is a temporary, the reference to `_x` returned by the conversion operator is not, and that the above code is unsafe.

But the output seems to prove that the example *is* safe, the lifetime of the temporary `Foo()` is extended by the existence of a const reference to one of its members.

Is this right? Where in the standard is this specified?

Comment: Returning references is more often a bad idea than a good one. This is a good example of such.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes So you declare `operator[]` as...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general rule, regarding temporaries, is that their life ends when the full expression they are part of ends (informally, when reaching the `;`).

> **12.2 Temporary objects**
>
> **3/** [...] Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception. The value computations and side effects of destroying a temporary object are associated only with the full-expression, not with any specific subexpression.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the temporary survives for the whole duration of function call. When  you do `foo (Foo ());` here's what happens:

1. temporary `Foo` is contructed, then
2. `operator const int&` is called on the temporary
3. `foo()` is called and this outputs `F`
4. once `foo()` returns temporary `Foo` is destroyed and this outputs `~`

Comment: To elaborate: the code is safe as long as `foo` does not store the reference.

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic here. All function arguments live in the scope of the caller, including temporaries. The temporary `Foo()` is constructed in the scope of the caller, and destroyed at the end of the line.

So whatever the function `foo()` does happens *before* its arguments in `main()` are destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

But your `Foo` instance here was always going to live until the semicolon ending the statement in which it was created. Passing a reference to a member into a function call didn't change that.

Try:

```
int const &ref = Foo();
foo(ref);
```

versus

```
Foo const &ref = Foo(); // or function returning temp
foo(ref);
```